# Facing application stop during GC

Tags: jvm

Need some advise:

I am using Linux operating system
I have 24 CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X5650  @ 2.67GHz in my machine
RAM: 24675112 kB
JDK version: java version "1.6.0_32"

My JVM setting:

```
-Xmx12288m 
-Xms12288m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m 
-XX:MaxNewSize=4096m 
-XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=128m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=256m 
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing 
-XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled 
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 
-XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing 
-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat 
-XX:+UseTLAB 
-XX:+ResizeTLAB 
-XX:TLABSize=512k 
-XX:+PrintGC 
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
-XX:-PrintConcurrentLocks 
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps 
-XX:+PrintReferenceGC 
-XX:+PrintJNIGCStalls 
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime 
-XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark 
-XX:ConcGCThreads=12 
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=12
```

my GC log:

```
2013-08-27T16:59:34.584-0500: 201544.846: [GC [1 CMS-initial-mark: 7548665K(8388608K)] 7973934K(12163520K), 0.5412390 secs] [Times: user=0.54 sys=0.00, real=0.54 secs]
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.5427300 seconds
2013-08-27T16:59:35.125-0500: 201545.387: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0018140 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0012720 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005850 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0016750 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0013800 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004860 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0010740 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0015250 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0012570 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0001500 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0012430 seconds
2013-08-27T16:59:48.240-0500: 201558.502: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 13.095/13.114 secs] [Times: user=72.62 sys=4.61, real=13.12 secs]
2013-08-27T16:59:48.240-0500: 201558.502: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
201558.502: [Preclean SoftReferences, 0.0003750 secs]201558.502: [Preclean WeakReferences, 0.0006710 secs]201558.503: [Preclean FinalReferences, 0.0001780 secs]201558.503: [Preclean PhantomReferenc
es, 0.0000170 secs]2013-08-27T16:59:48.265-0500: 201558.527: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.025/0.025 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2013-08-27T16:59:48.265-0500: 201558.527: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2013-08-27T16:59:53.952-0500: 201564.214: [GC 201564.214: [ParNew202182.528: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000110 secs]202182.528: [WeakReference, 1015 refs, 0.0001720 secs]202182.528: [FinalReference, 1625 refs, 0.0025210 secs]202182.531: [PhantomReference, 1 refs, 0.0000050 secs]202182.531: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000100 secs] (promotion failed): 3774912K->3774912K(3774912K), 619.3859950 secs]202183.600: [CMS CMS: abort preclean due to time 2013-08-27T17:10:14.937-0500: 202185.199: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 7.271/626.671 secs] [Times: user=699.20 sys=98.95, real=626.55 secs]
 (concurrent mode failure)202189.179: [SoftReference, 614 refs, 0.0000710 secs]202189.179: [WeakReference, 5743 refs, 0.0007600 secs]202189.180: [FinalReference, 3380 refs, 0.0004430 secs]202189.180: [PhantomReference, 212 refs, 0.0000260 secs]202189.180: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000180 secs]: 8328471K->4813636K(8388608K), 18.5940310 secs] 11323577K->4813636K(12163520K), [CMS Perm : 208169K->208091K(346920K)], 637.9802050 secs] [Times: user=705.47 sys=98.79, real=637.85 secs]
**Total time for which application threads were stopped: 637.9820120 seconds**
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0047480 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006330 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0052820 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0008540 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0008090 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002400 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0058850 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0008530 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0010900 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006730 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006930 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0012200 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0016290 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0007660 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005650 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0002880 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005440 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006790 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0007510 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003870 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0007190 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0016670 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0007340 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0014800 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0019800 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0009810 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0010530 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006650 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0009600 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0007110 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0011330 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006940 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0008220 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0015080 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0007340 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0003830 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005620 seconds
2013-08-27T17:10:39.422-0500: 202209.684: [GC 202209.685: [ParNew202210.354: [SoftReference, 0 refs, 0.0000130 secs]202210.355: [WeakReference, 3827 refs, 0.0003690 secs]202210.355: [FinalReference, 3925 refs, 0.0024380 secs]202210.357: [PhantomReference, 99 refs, 0.0000220 secs]202210.357: [JNI Weak Reference, 0.0000090 secs]: 3355520K->419392K(3774912K), 0.6728950 secs] 8169156K->5597366K(12163520K), 0.6730540 secs] [Times: user=7.13 sys=0.00, real=0.68 secs]
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.6743080 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0013680 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0004720 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0006960 seconds
Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0015600 seconds
```

My application that running is getting "Service Temporary Unavailable"

Comment: How did you determine that you get it because the garbage collector interrupts your application?

Comment: Have you tried without all the "-XX"?

Comment: My first piece of advice would be to eliminate all the configuration flags except perhaps setting the maximum heap size.  I would also use the generational collector, not CMS.

Comment: I would also use Java 7, not 6.

Comment: Each time users has the "Service unavailable" message, we will see the message "**Total time for which application threads were stopped: 637.9820120 seconds** (the stopped time is mostly > 5 minutes).

Comment: I yet to try the removing of all -XX as this is the production environment, and testing need to be done before implement it. And we are going to upgrade java to version 7 (testing in still in progress in Dev tier) and will be roll out to Production end of year.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I'm going to answer it for completion as the other suggestions/comments miss the point.

The GC log record in question is at 201564.214.
It is a ParNew (young generational collection) that suffers from a promotion failure (tenured space does not have enough capacity to accept data being promoted). But I don't think this is the real problem but rather the consequence of another underlying problem.

The odd thing here is the the preclean phase has collected 98.95 seconds of system time *and* the Full GC (concurrent mode failure) is reporting 98.79 seconds of system time. These numbers suggest that the underlying problem isn't with GC but with how the JVM is interacting with the OS. Garbage collectors run in user space and should not accumulate system time.

One of the things that can cause this is in how much work the OS needs to perform to manage memory. If the system is in low memory conditions the OS may be spending a *lot* of time managing it. This could be further aggravated by competing/heavy I/O operations or the use of transparent large pages in Linux. It's hard to say without further data. That said, you need to look at the system you're running on in this situations to get a better handle on what is happening.